# Default line spacing of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

What is default line spacing in `UILabel`. I need to calculate how many lines can be in `UILabel` with set frame.

Comment: The spacing depends on the font you use. Do you need to calculate the size required for an arbitrary text?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the default line spacing is in a UILabel, but I used the below to calculate the number of lines a UILabel wants to be.

```
extension UILabel {

    var preferredNumberOfLines: Int {
        guard let currentText = self.text else {
            return 0
        }

        let labelSize = currentText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: self.bounds.width,
                                                              height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                                 options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                                 attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : self.font],
                                                 context: nil)

        return Int(ceil(CGFloat(labelSize.height) / self.font.lineHeight))
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because I don't have a text. I need to calculate how many lines can be potentially in label.

Comment: @JaSHin UILabel potentially can have unlimited number of lines. Could you please elaborate what you mean when you say that you don't have a text? Related to what you need to calculate the number of lines?